# Общий файл excel на сервере для редактирования

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, excel

есть нужда в реализации общего файла excel ( здесь будет таблица учета рассылок) на сервере, к которой будут обращаться пользователи через страницу браузера (цели обращения могут быть абсолютно разные, от просмотра до редактирования).
Вопрос в том, как это лучше реализовать и какие советы будут?

Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: дак положите его на сервер, пусть смотрят. Если вам нужно файл и читать и записывать, то потрудитесь нормально вопрос сформулировать.

Comment: exel to sql. там будет обрабатываться, не будет проблем с доступностью файла, всегда можно выгрузить отчёт

Comment: @Bloom проблема в том, что пользователям удобно работать именно в excel файле

Comment: @teran да, нужно не только читать, но и редактировать, вопрос поправил ( вроде как)

Comment: Храните данные в БД, по запросу на чтение формируйте эксель файл средствами пхп, и сохраняйте его до следующего внесения изменений, потом перегенирите заново.

Comment: @teran в моем случае так сделать не выйдет, т.к. эти excel таблицы ведутся очень давно, и они очень специфичны, не имеют строгой структуры, как таблицы в бд

Comment: Используй гугл таблицы

Comment: @РашенБеарsaystohellMonica спасибо, но у меня вопрос немного в другом=)

Answer (score 1):

Всё-таки лучшим решением будет размещение таблицы в [google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets) с  раздачей прав пользователям.